# Need certificate (.crt file) but OpenVPN only provides a config (.ovpn) file?

Tags: openvpn

When I try to configure a new vpn connection in Ubuntu, it's asking for a CA certificate (.crt) file but I only had the option of downloading a .ovpn file from the OpenVPN portal.

Can I get a CA certificate from the .ovpn file?

Comment: Certificates and keys can be embedded in the `.ovpn` file. Have you actually tried using it yet?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few elements of your post that are unclear to me (like what you mean by the OpenVPN portal), but I have played around with ovpn files enough to answer the question in general terms.  The answer is "probably".

OVPN files are plain text configuration files that can store CA public keys (along with public and private keys) in .pem file - although these do not have to be present if not required, or can be references to files. (Having a single file makes deployment easier).

The ovpn file can be edited with a standard text editor - eg notepad or vi - and if it contains ..... the contents between those lines are a standard pem format key you can copy and paste into a web box or file.

Also, you can forgo the gui on ubuntu altogether and put the vpn file in /etc/openvpn/client and manually use openvpn (I don't know if doing that integrates with the gui - I never use the gui)

Comment: There are several certificates in there, not sure which is the one I need. And do I include the "---BEGIN CERTIFICATE---" line?   The OpenVPN Portal meaning the webpage I see when hitting the ip address of the vpn server.

Comment: Also, I noticed on Windows it does not ask for any kind of CA Certificate when configuring a VPN, yet on Linux, the certificate is mandatory in the gui?  What is that about ?

Comment: Yes, you should copy the ---BEGIN CERTIFICATE---  and ---END CERTIFICATE--- lines.    You likely need all the certificates.     An OPENVPN server does not come with a website/web page - so this would be something added on my your provider.

Comment: I don't know about Windows not asking for a CA - but if you are a using public/private key scheme (as appears to be the case) and the provider is creating config files for lots of users, you would want to have a CA as it helps prevent MITM attacks.   I expect its possible to run a VPN config without a CA, but that would reduce security of the VPN.   By way of close analogy, when browsing an https website your computer has a list of CAs bundled with the browser.  If you use an HTTPS site where the CA cert is not bundled/added you get an error, but you can proceed past the error.

Comment: OP is most likely connecting to OpenVPN Access Server. It has a web GUI.